# Webscraping Using Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to the Beautifulsoup package in Python and am getting some unexpected results when using the .findAll() function. I am needing to extract the string immediately to the right of /File/ from the light blue highlighted portion of this webpage:

[image]

Here is my Beautifulsoup/Python code:

[image]

The first two lines of code work fine, but pdf1 is empty. Can anyone shed some light on why the .findAll() function is not finding this a tag (I assume I am making a syntax error, just not sure where)?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows a browser output of the current HTML I guess? Did you check if it's the same content in `page.text`?  This might reveal any client-side modifications which cannot be handled by BS, as indicated by `ngRepeat`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct: The content of page.text is not the same as the browser output. Can you point me to any web resources to learn more about why this is happening?

Comment: Here's an article explaining the different approaches: [Client-side vs. server-side rendering](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-exactly-is-client-side-rendering-and-hows-it-different-from-server-side-rendering-bd5c786b340d). The thing which tipped me off was the `ng` prefix of your class, which indicates the use of [AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) which uses JavaScript in the browser to render certain parts of your HTML. You'd need to have to execute the JavaScript to render the same HTML for BS.